# How to handle reject transaction in metamask extension

Tags: javascript, metamask

If we creating a transaction to smart contract via metamask and user doesn't confirm it, it stays in list of transactions and user can send it much later, or reject it in another tab. Is there any way to check that transaction was rejected or still waits for user confirmation

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the address of user from which he/she is sending amount. And then keep listening for pay event of your contract passing user's address in filter. This will trigger pay event only when the amount is send from user's address and you can do further processing there.

Answer (score 0):

Upon 'Reject' in Metamask you can examine the 'error' callback.
The field "message" will contain:
- "User denied transaction signature" for Metamask
- "User denied transaction signature" for Cipher
- "Invalid Message Body" for Toshi/Coinbase
- "cancelled" for Trust